# Problems using Math.ceil()

Tags: java

I am attempting to use the ceil() method of the Math class to type cast a double; initialized at 0.4, the ceil() method should type cat it to 1.0. Yet, for some reason I can't figure out, it's not working. Some advice would be much appreciated.

```
double num = 0.4;

System.out.println(num); // 0.4

Math.ceil(num);

System.out.println(num); // 0.4
```

Comment: refer this. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_ceil.htm

Comment: Read about Call by reference vs Call by value

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
num = Math.ceil(num);
```

What's happening is you are not assigning the  value from Math.ceil(num) to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning the value of `Math.ceil`. The value of `num` remains unchanged.

To print the ceiling of `num` you can either put the call in sys out or just try following code:

```
double num = 0.4;

System.out.println(num); // 0.4

double ceiledNum=Math.ceil(num);

System.out.println(ceiledNum);
```